# Permission denied (publickey,password). while using ssh to login

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ssh, server

I'm trying to login to the server using ssh, and I realise that I forgot my password. I'm using this command:

```
ssh root@this-is-my-domain.com
```

I don't know what to do, I searched for a solution but nothing helped me. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
Any help?

Comment: Do you mean you forget the password for your keyfile, but do you also have the password for the user at this server?

Comment: I forgot my ssh password on my local computer, otherwise I'm using Digital Ocean and there I know my account.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using ssh public key, and you just forget your root password, you can reset your root password using Digital Ocean control panel

If you are using ssh public key and you forget the password to that key, you can force SSH to use your Digital Ocean password instead of the key

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```

Comment: should I replace user and password? Sorry for my question, but I'm a little confused

Comment: The password that you forgot was only for that key file. You can totally delete the key file if you don't think you'll ever remember it (it's inside `.ssh` folder in your home folder), and then you can remove the corresponding public key from the remote server, and replace it with a new one if you like.

Comment: I clarified my answer. If you simply forget the root password to this server, you can reset it in your Digital Ocean control panel.

Answer (score 4):

If you get `Permission denied` while using ssh to login, you probably need to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Change `PasswordAuthentication` value to `yes`.

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: And don't forget to restart ssh after that: `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: This must be done on the server or on the client?

Comment: The configuration is done at the server and also the service restart

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem while trying to ssh into another machine. These steps helped me to get to a solution:

1 -- `sudo passwd root` - Change root password (optional)

2 -- `sudo install openssh-server`

3 -- `cd /etc/ssh`

4 -- `sudo nano sshd_config`
(Now uncomment line PermitRootLogin and change it to yes,
Uncomment Authorized keys file,
Uncomment PasswordAuthentication and change it to yes)

5 -- `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

Now you are good to go, and can easily connect over ssh using the root account.

6 -- `su -`

7 -- `ssh root@ip-of-device`

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to login as root as it is disabled by default.

If you have been given a username and password try using those instead. However if your root user has been enabled, root is sometimes the default password for Ubuntu.